# Scala - should ExecutorService be used for splitting work among the threads?

Tags: scala, concurrency

Coming from a Java background, a problem of splitting multiple tasks amongst multiple threads can be easily using ExecutorService and submitting tasks through that interface. Would you say the same approach makes sense in Scala world? If so, is there a Scala version of that API?

If no, what approach would you recommend? Actors seem to be a bit of an overkill, as I would envision them to be used for thread communication mostly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The pure Scala way**

Scala's concurrency model is based around the Erlang actor model. It's a slightly different approach. To fully exploit Scala's concurrency, use something like Akka. The basic usage idea is fairly simple.

The most simple task is using a `Future`(an asynchronous action). Read more about this [HERE](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html). The Executors framework is not the approach you should take. There are quite a few options to achieve powerful multi-threaded| parallelisms in your Scala applications:

1. [Akka](http://akka.io/)
2. [Lift](http://liftweb.net/) actors(when using the Lift web framework).
3. [Finagle](http://twitter.github.io/finagle/)(The Twitter RPC framework).
4. The default Scala actors library, DEPRECATED in Scala 2.10. Read more [HERE](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/12396).

**The Scala/Java interoperability approach**

Actors may be a drastic change to the way you are used to implementing concurrency, and Java doesn't have shortcomings there. So you can still use the Executor framework for multi-threading in Scala applications.

It means you will rely almost entirely on native Java concurrency structures, but it gets you there with having to change much. Read more on how to do that in Scala [HERE](http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/concurrency.html).

Comment: Don't you think it is overengineering?

Comment: perhaps you will be surprised to know that both scala and akka actors use java concurrency underneath ;-) From what @Bober02 have written he doesn't need to communicate between threads (or actors), just to parallelize some amount of work between threads, thus I've claimed Scala/Akka/Lift actors or even Finagle approach is like using a sledgehammer to crack nuts: 1) all systems above will recuire relatively lot of setup and code to be written for such simple task 2) they will spend extra bookkeeping work (compared to ExecutorService) on tasks you don't need: failover and communication

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to go the actor route, then you can certainly make due with an `ExecutionContext` and `Futures`.  Provided you had an implicit `ExecutionContext` in scope, you could do something like this if you had a fixed set of tasks that you wanted to run concurrently:

```
val f1 = Future{
  //do something here
}  
val f2 = Future{
  //do something else here
} 
val aggFut = for{
  f1Val <- f1
  f2Val <- f2
} yield (f1Val, f2Val)

aggFut onComplete{
  case Success(tup) => //handle success case here
  case Failure(ex) => //handle failure here
}
```

In this example, the tup in the `Success` would contain the result of f1 and f2 in that order.

If you had a dynamic number of parallel tasks to run, you could do something like this:

```
val futs = someList.map(item => Future{...})
val aggFut = Future.sequence(futs)
aggFut onComplete{
  case Success(list) => //handle success case here
  case Failure(ex) => //handle failure here
}
```

In this success case, the `Success` would wrap a List of whatever type is returned from the `Future` function.

Lastly, if you wanted to perform some sequence based set of async tasks, you could do something like this:

```
val fut = for{
  val1 <- Future{...}
  val2 <- Future{...}
} yield val2
fut onComplete{
  case Success(v2) => //handle success case here
  case Failure(ex) => //handle failure here
}
```

In this case, the value `val1` would be available to the `Future` that is calculating `val2`.  This is only really scratching the surface.  If you are interested in learning more, you should check out http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html

Answer (score 1):

It's a good use case for [parallel collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html) (if tasks are relatively heavy):

```
val TasksNumber = 27
val tasks = List.fill(TasksNumber) { () => Thread.sleep(10000) }
tasks.par.map(t => t.apply)
```